# Custom Component class methods are throwing error when called

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-component

I've created a Custom Component in layout/XML which has 2 TextViews and 2 Buttons.
In its supporting class I simply have buttons increment and decrement the value of one of the TextViews

```
public class NumberStepper extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

//Define the elements (Children) of the compound view
public TextView tvStepperName, tvStepperValue;
public Button btnIncrement, btnDecrement;

private int statValue;
public NumberStepper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    //tvStepperName.setText(name);
    statValue = 0;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.numberstepper, this);
    loadComponents();

    }
private void loadComponents(){
    tvStepperName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStepperName);
    tvStepperValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStepperValue);
    btnIncrement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIncrement);
    btnDecrement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecrement);

    btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDecrement.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvStepperValue.setText("" + statValue);

}

public void setLabel(String str){
    tvStepperName.setText(str);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnIncrement:
            statValue++;
            tvStepperValue.setText("" + statValue);
            tvStepperName.setText("HELLO");
        break;
    case R.id.btnDecrement:
        if(statValue > 0){
            statValue--;
        }
        tvStepperValue.setText("" + statValue);
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Next I created another XML layout that has 5 or 6 of these compound components

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.nsholmes.bballStats.componets.NumberStepper
    android:id="@+id/ccOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.nsholmes.bballStats.componets.NumberStepper>
<com.nsholmes.bballStats.componets.NumberStepper
    android:id="@+id/ccTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.nsholmes.bballStats.componets.NumberStepper>
```

In this layout's support class (which extends Activity) I set the compound component variables, setContentView(),and I attempt the following:

```
ccOne = (NumberStepper)findViewById(R.id.ccOne);
    ccOne.setLabel("Label Name");
```

I get an error stating - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo). I only get this error when I call setLabel().

07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nsholmes.bballStats/com.nsholmes.bballStats.games.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at com.nsholmes.bballStats.games.Game.loadComponents(Game.java:34)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at com.nsholmes.bballStats.games.Game.onCreate(Game.java:27)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-31 17:54:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(11454):    ... 11 more

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks
THis is the full layout for the numberstepper

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStepperName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FreeThrow"
    android:layout_weight="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnIncrement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:text="@string/plusSign" />"

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDecrement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:text="@string/minusSign" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStepperValue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_weight="30" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should post the full code for the custom component.

Comment: And attach an error from logcat

Comment: most likely findViewById returns null, but I'd really like to see your full exception stack trace.

Comment: Here's everything I got in terms of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be that with the way you are trying to find the view. As I understand it `findViewById(..)` works based off of `setContentView(..)` and since there is no content view set in your class the view returned is null.

Maybe you can try to find the TextView from the inflated view.

```
.....
private int statValue;
private View mView;

public NumberStepper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    //tvStepperName.setText(name);
    statValue = 0;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numberstepper, this);
    loadComponents();

}

private void loadComponents(){
    tvStepperName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvStepperName);
    tvStepperValue = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvStepperValue);
    btnIncrement = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnIncrement);
    btnDecrement = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnDecrement);
.....
}
.....
.....
```

Comment: That was it. It worked. I'm not sure I totally understand why. The LinearLayout class does not provide a setContentView() so creating a View variable allows...?

Comment: I am relatively new to android development so someone might be able to explain this better. I will try to the best of my knowledge :)

The `setContentView(...)` is available on the `Activity` class and any custom class that extend it. This is basically where you have your main layout loaded in the `onCreate(...)` method.

When create a custom layout based on `LinearLayout` (or any other layout for that matter) you are essentially creating a `View`. So a view by itself won't have a `setContentView(...)` method. With a custom view you have to inflate your custom layout and use it.

Answer (score 1):

One of your `findViewById` calls is returning null, this could be happening on the following lines (you didn't post your full layout and code, so I'm taking a blind shot here):

```
ccOne = (NumberStepper)findViewById(R.id.ccOne);

tvStepperName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStepperName);
```

Edit:

Since now we see your full stack trace the error is on line 34 in your `loadComponents` function. You're calling findViewById on your NumberStepper to find R.id.tvStepperName and R.id.tvStepperValue, are you sure you have `View`s with these names inside your `NumberStepper` in layout xml?

Comment: Looks like the contents of your second xml snippet is outside both NumberSteppers. NumberStepper tag should wrap around views it should contain. If it's not how it should work you should find NumberStepper's parent view which will be your LinearLayout and then you should call `findViewById` on this LinearLayout.

Comment: There are two layout files here. One is the numberStepper.xml which holds the compound component. and the other uses multiple instances of the compound component (numberStepper)

Comment: Post your layouts as they are. Did you understand what I was talking about in my previous comment?